# storyboard - delegate for popover

Tags: ios, storyboard, popover

I'm working with popover, inside the popover have contain a uitableview, and i want get value when tap on uitableview, i create delegate inside

popover.h

```
@class PopOverVCDelegate;
@protocol PopOverVCDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)getValue:(int)value;

@end

@interface ..
{
@property(nonatomic)id<PopOverVCDelegate> delegate;
}
@end
```

popover.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate getValue:[indexPath row]];
}
```

and mainclass receive delegate is

mainclass.h

```
#import "PopOverVC.h"
@interface MainClassVC : UIViewController<PopupCatchupVCDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{}
```

mainclass.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showPopover"])
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        UIPopoverController *p = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        p.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomPopoverBackground class];
        self.popoverController = p;        
        popoverController.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)getValue:(int)value
{
    NSLog(@"adsf-%d",value);
}
```

I don't get any value from delegate. Anybody help me, i using storyboard and call popover from push navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In popover.h you declared protocol PopOverVCDelegate  & in mainclass.h you are implementing  PopupCatchupVCDelegate protocol. Your mainclass should confirm to PopOverVCDelegate.

```
@interface MainClassVC : UIViewController<PopOverVCDelegate, PopupCatchupVCDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
```

Also you should check if delegate method is implemented or not before calling it like-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getValue:)])
        [self.delegate getValue:[indexPath row]];
}
```

**EDIT**

I looked into storyboard and noticed that, your delegate is not getting to set to correct controller. You are setting delegate to p(UIPopoverController), you should set it to contentViewController(PopOver) of popover.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"idenPopover"])
    {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        UIPopoverController *p = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        p.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomPopoverBackground class];
        self.popoverController = p;
        self.popoverController.delegate = self;

        //set delegate to PopOver 
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)p.contentViewController;
        PopOver *popOver = (PopOver*)navigationController.topViewController;
        [popOver setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already call delegate at preparesegue is -> popoverController.delegate = self;

Comment: I am talking about confirming to protocol not setting delegate. Put below line in your mainclass.h @interface MainClassVC : UIViewController<PopOverVCDelegate, PopupCatchupVCDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

Comment: I have not used prepareForSegue but I think you are doing something wrong there. Have you properly set custom class in storyboard for popover.

Comment: Can you download code from me by link here -> http://www.mediafire.com/?90t8gojmk18h2ia